# flutter - scrolling listview inside listview builder

Tags: list, listview, dart, flutter

I have a 'Filter' and below that is a list of soccer matches. I Wrap 'Filter and' listview builder' with a ListView (so that the overload writing under blablabla is resolved). But there is something strange when you scroll normally. scroll to the list that doesn't work. there is only a 'glow effect', but I scroll from the 'Filter menu' above, the scroll works. How do I make the scroll run normally?

[image: see image]

My snipped code:

```
Widget _buildListView(FixtureModel model, BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: model.getFixturesCount() == 0
            ? Center(child: Text('No fixtures found'))
            : ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () => _onTap(context),
                                child: Container(
                                    margin:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                                            child:
                                                Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.github)),
                                        Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Liga Premier Inggris',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 5.0, top: 2.0),
                                            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                                size: 17.0))
                                      ],
                                    )),
                              )),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                            child: Text(
                              '4',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                              iconSize: 20.0,
                              icon: Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.calendarAlt,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {})
                        ],
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        height: 0.0,
                      ),
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: model.fixtureList == null
                                ? 0
                                : model.getFixturesCount(),
                            itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                              var fixture = model.fixtureList[i];

                              return FixtureListItem(fixture: fixture);
                            },
                          ))
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ));
  }
```

Comment: In your ListView -add shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

Comment: @anmol.majhail hello sir, hope you are in good condition. do you understand my problem this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293164/flutter-double-http-request-when-moving-another-page?noredirect=1#comment93468010_53293164 ?

Comment: yes, You need to make Tab Bars Data Persistent - for - DetailMatchTab(widget.fixture) class use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin , comment article give good example of that - https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc

Comment: class _DetailMatchTabState extends State<DetailMatchTab> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<DetailMatchTab> {}

Comment: @anmol.majhail yeah, i added that before
see https://pastebin.com/5wENUb1j

Comment: ok , Before -  return ScopedModelDescendant add - super.build(context);

Comment: uhh, I found it. I declare List <Standings> = [] before adding new data. 
Thank you for your time sir @anmol.majhail

Comment: ok good, Happy Coding !

Comment: Hi sir @anmol.majhail, do you know in this case? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617360/flutter-how-do-distance-filters-then-display-lists-based-on-the-nearest-positi)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your ListView add:

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

To take Out Filter From ListView: `remove physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), then in ListView`

```
body: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                     Filter(),
                     Expanded(
                        child: ListView()
                     ),
                ]
            )
```

Comment: Wow ... cool, thanks you for your help.

one thing, is it possible that the 'filter' is standing upright then when the scroll is just a list that moves?

Comment: Yes Move the Filter Out of ListView, In Column 1st Widget - Filter 2nd Listview.
body: Column children: <Widget>[Filter(),Expanded (ListView())]  i Updated answer with Code

Comment: nice dude.. you save my day, very much help.

Comment: @Muhammad - will check later as m outside now.

Comment: @MuhammadImanudin  - i haven't played with Slivers in that much depth - won't be able to help but you can check - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverOverlapInjector-class.html & https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22393

Comment: (y) I made it transparent, a little layout to make it look stacked on sliverlist & sliverappbar. thanks thank you sir,

Comment: Good - Try to Self Answer your Question then - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119622/flutter-anyone-know-how-to-create-photo-with-stack-silverlist
@MuhammadImanudin