# flutter - double http request when moving another page

Tags: json, api, http, dart, flutter

I encountered a problem when I picked up the http request List  which continued to increase when I went to the tab page and returned to its original page (see picture for result).

[image: when the first build]

then, after leaving another page and returning to the original

[image: after leaving another page and returning to the original]

how to optimize this?

see my code below:

```
class HomeTabDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final Fixture fixture;
  final FixtureModel model;

  HomeTabDetail({this.fixture, this.model});

  @override
  _HomeTabDetailState createState() => _HomeTabDetailState();
}

class _HomeTabDetailState extends State<HomeTabDetail>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;
  // BannerAd bannerAd;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
    print('initstate called');
    controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
    // FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
    // bannerAd = buildBanner()..load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // bannerAd?.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
    print('dispose called');
    super.dispose();
  }

  static final targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    keywords: <String>['flutterio', 'beautiful apps'],
    contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
    childDirected: false,
    testDevices: <String>[], // Android emulators are considered test devices
  );

  BannerAd buildBanner() {
    return BannerAd(
        adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
        size: AdSize.smartBanner,
        targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
          print("bannerAd event is $event");
        });
  }

  Future loadData() async {
    await Future.wait([
      widget.model.fetchVenue(widget.fixture.venueId.toString()),
      widget.model.fetchCountry(widget.fixture.league.countryId.toString()),
      widget.model.fetchStandingTeams(widget.fixture.season.id.toString())
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // bannerAd.show();
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Info Pertandingan'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: controller,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(text: 'RINCIAN'),
              Tab(text: 'MEDIA'),
              Tab(text: 'LINEUP'),
              Tab(text: 'KLASEMEN'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: ScopedModelDescendant<FixtureModel>(
            builder: (context, child, model) {
          return TabBarView(
            controller: controller,
            children: <Widget>[
              DetailMatchTab(widget.fixture),
              MediaMatchTab(),
              LineupMatchTab(),
              KlasemenMatchTab()
            ],
          );
        }));
  }
}
```

here fetchStandingTeams() method

```
Future<List<StandingTeams>> fetchStandingTeams(String seasonId) async {
    var response =
        await http.get(Constant.standingById + seasonId + Constant.apiToken);
    var responseBody = json.decode(response.body)['data'];

    for (var standingJson in responseBody) {
      print(standingJson);

      for (var data in standingJson['standings']['data']) {
        var standings = StandingTeams.fromJson(data);
        print(standings);
        addToStandingList(standings);
      }
    }

    _isLoadingVenue = false;
    notifyListeners();

    return _standingTeams;
  }
```

Comment: take a look at this; https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc

Comment: It seems like you re-add the standings to the list every time initState is called, but never re-initialize the list of standings. Maybe just add a line that declares the list as empty before you repopulate it with the info you retreived?

Comment: @diegoveloper yes, I added that before. see https://pastebin.com/5wENUb1j
for each tab. but for the code above as a controller of all tabs

Comment: Uh oh, so true.. thank you @Kris